# How to modify global variables?

Tags: python, global

Here is a simplified version of the problem of updating globals —
in `test.py` I have:

```
k1 = 1

def set_v(k, v):
  if k in globals():
    globals()[k] = v;
    read_v()

def read_v():
  print("after {}".format(k1))
```

The code run from python interpreter after doing:

```
from test.py import *
```

yields...

```
>>> k1
1
>>> set_v('k1',2)
after 2
>>> set_v('k1',3)
after 3
>>> k1
1
```

I can't fathom this.
`k1` has global scope as `read_v()` sees it in the global `dict`.
Why is global `k1` visible to interpreter not being changed?
I have tried `setattr(module, var, val)`...but that's no different than this.

Comment: FWIW, when Python makes it really hard to do something, it's often a sign that maybe you shouldn't be _trying_ to do it. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Globals in Python are only global within a module.

If you want to modify a global within an imported module, you need to access it using `module.variable`.

In the context of your test, this means:

```
import test.py as test
from test.py import *

print(test.k1)

set_v('k1',2)
set_v('k1',3)

print(test.k1)
```

Output:

```
1
after 2
after 3
3
```

Comment: I am not sure --  If you do "from xxx import *" it's supposed to read it into the global name space. you are talking about globals have reference to modules, there is only one module here.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `from test import *` you bring all those objects and functions into your namespace. You have a reference to `k1` while `test` also has a reference to `k1`. But the references aren't the same. They are different.

Try this:

```
>>> import test
>>> from test import *
>>> set_v('k1', 3)
after 3
>>> k1
1
>>> test.k1
3
```

Modify your `set_v` function to also print out the id. You'll see that `test`'s `k1` and the `k1` that is imported into your REPL session are different.

*Conclusion*: Each version of `k1` resides in their respective namespaces.

Comment: that is the question -- why are they different ? Isn't importing something with "from xx import *" explicitly stating  that you want the two to be same? Otherwise you would scope the variable and they can be accessed by their dot notation.

Comment: @schhibba Like I said. They belong to different namespaces. By doing an import, you do not merge the namespaces. You just import the variables from the foreign namespace to yours.

Comment: @schhibba I should mention a copy is imported. The original file has its own version. That's the concept of a namespace.

Comment: This is really disjoint. Interpreter prints "k1" value because the test.py is read into the interpreter namespace. However; what you are pointing out is that it's making a copy of every variable and this is not the same as "global" space for the code.  If I am using "from test import *" the test.k1 construct is not available -- meaning "k1" on it's own in the interpreter global namespace is a dangling reference. At the very least it's inconsistent behavior by the interpreter.

Comment: @schhibba Not at all. Just because the construct isnt available doesn't mean it doesn't exist at that time!

Comment: @COLDSPEED - thanks for your patience; but I can't really fathom the wisdom of this behavior How can one use a interpreter for even playing around with functions -- I can never set the value of "k1" in interpreter and hope the code (test.py) to see it!